# SQL Server : insert records into a table with a counter element

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am converting data from a 3rd party provider into an inhouse SQL Server database. The incoming table has data which looks like this:

```
ID   Element1    Element2    Element3
-------------------------------------
 1      43582       1           7
 2      46852       2           6
 3      46852       4           4
 4      47895       2           9
```

I have a script which executes an

```
Insert into.... 
    Select..... 
    From......
```

which correctly imports the data from the source table properly except for 1 element in the destination table.

When I run my script, the resulting table looks like this:

```
ID    Location   LocationCounter   Drawer1   Drawer2
----------------------------------------------------
 1      43582          NULL          1         7
 2      46852          NULL          2         6
 3      46852          NULL          4         4
 4      47895          NULL          2         9
```

I need to modify my script to populate the `LocationCounter` column.  I can default the value to 1 but in the case of location 46852, the first record inserted needs to have a `LocationCounter` value of 1 and the second record inserted needs to have a `LocationCounter` value of 2.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use something like `select id, element1 as location, row_number() over (partition by element1 order by id) as LocationCounter, element2 as drawer1, element3 as drawer2 from ....`

Comment: Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Adding comment as answer...

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by element1.

```
select id, element1 as location, 
    row_number() over (partition by element1 order by id) as LocationCounter, 
    your_other_columns
from your_staging_table
```